# question about Dynkin's π-λ Theorem

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have seen in class Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system )

One of the applications of it  that we saw is the following (these are my notes) :

- We consider set $A$ of all the intervals of the form $(-\infty,a]$
- By application of Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem , we conclude that its generated sigma-algebra is the set of Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$. The borel sets were previously described as the sigma-algebra generated by all the intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ (let's call this $I$).

I forgot to write something down and now I'm stuck... can someone explain to me how this is an application of Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem ?  I assume this has something to do with $I$ also being a Dynkin system but I can't conclude from this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $\pi$-system of half intervals is contained in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (which will be your Dynkin system, not $I$).

The $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem tells you that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $\pi$-system is contained in that generated by $I$ (which is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). *The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra that contains $I$*. Once you know that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $\pi$-system also contains $I$ (and this is easier to verify), you conclude they must be the same.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. I already know that A in included in the borel set, so applying that sigma-algebra this inclusion, I get the same result you get when you use the π-λ theorem, so I don't see the point of using it

Comment: @lezebulon The point is that for the uniqueness theorem for measures it suffices to check that they agree on the $\pi$-system.

Comment: So I see you point now, it appears it is not really needed here to use the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem for this conclusion.